# SQL filtering on a column with the minimum attribute

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to make a select statement that will sort out unwanted rows based on a column: Name and Date.

In the following example I have 3 columns whereas the column: Name can have multiple duplicates but with another Date & Address value. My goal is to sort on Minimum Date & only show that one.  This should be done for the rest of the table too.

```
**Name    Date          Address**
  David   19/05/2015    Longstreet
  David   19/05/2016    Longstreet2
  David   19/05/2017    Longstreet3
  Tom     18/05/2015    Shortstreet1
  Tom     18/05/2016    Shortstreet2
  Milan   17/05/2015    Bobstreet
```

This should result in the following output:

```
**Name    Date          Address**
  David   19/05/2015    Longstreet
  Tom     18/05/2015    Shortstreet
  Milan   17/05/2015    Bobstreet
```

Thank you for your cooperation.

Comment: can't test as i don't have database but try this: `select name, min(date), address from table group by name`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select t1.name, t.dt, t1.address
from (
select name, min(date) dt
from tablename
group by name) t
join tablename t1 on t1.name = t.name and t1.date = t.dt
```

You would select `minimum` of date column grouped by name.

Comment: But it does not guarantee of `Address` from the min date row.

Comment: You would get a syntax error here because you haven't aggregated address.

Comment: @BJones..mysql allows you to do that

Comment: That's not what it says [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-handling.html)

Comment: you should look at that more closely.

Comment: Ah! Good to know. I wasn't paying attention. Thanks for pointing that out.